# "Rollback" command in MySQL does not active?

Tags: mysql

I added a value to my table by this command

```
insert into employees 
( 
emp_no,
birth_date,
first_name,
last_name,
gender,
hire_date
) VALUES
(
999901,
'1986-04-21',
'John',
'Smith',
'M',
'2011-01-01'
);
```

Then checked by this command

```
select * from employees where emp_no = 999901;
```

So, I saw the data as I added.
Then I del the data by this command

```
delete from employees where emp_no = 999901;
```

And tried to rollback by this command right after the command above

```
rollback;
```

But the data still not rollback as I wish ?

Could you please explain for me about this problem ? I think the rollback cascade could work right after the command ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Either execute the queries in explicit transaction or disable implicit commit. *And tried to rollback by this command right after the command above* Unclear. What command(s) you'd like to be rollbacked? PS. Remember - rollback does NOT revert the table's autoincrement property.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run `ROLLBACK;` to undo your changes, you need to first start a transaction

```sql
START TRANSACTION; <--- run this first

insert into employees 
( 
emp_no,
birth_date,
first_name,
last_name,
gender,
hire_date
) VALUES
(
999901,
'1986-04-21',
'John',
'Smith',
'M',
'2011-01-01'
);

select * from employees where emp_no = 999901;

delete from employees where emp_no = 999901;

rollback;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html